# gunicorn not found on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I want to deploy a very basic Django app on Heroku. I followed the instructions, but the browser shows me the Heroku error page and the heroku logs say

```
bash: gunicorn: command not found
```

I have gunicorn in my requirements.txt and configured the wsgi.py and Procfile as instructed by the documentation. What else can I try?

Edit: I also tried to install gunicorn manually on Heroku (`heroku run pip install gunicorn`), which worked fine, so I am pretty sure that gunicorn is installed. Why doesn't Heroku find it?

Edit 2: It seems that I can install gunicorn manually (`heroku run bash` and then `pip install gunicorn`:

```
~ $ gunicorn
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: No application module specified.
```

but when i log out and log in to the bash again, i get:

```
~ $ gunicorn
bash: gunicorn: command not found
```

Heroku seems to install but then discard gunicorn. How can that be?

Comment: Can you post your Procfile and project.wsgi file please?

Answer (score 2):

Hi got the same problem but this might help:

Go to this:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python

And try to run this command in project's root terminal:

```
heroku buildpacks:set git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
```

and then update heroku with running below command:

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: The command could be `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`. This worked for me because I already had a python app so I didn't cloned the Heroku's python app template. Thanks